# Удаление скобок максимальной вложенности

Tags: c, список, структуры

сделано для проверки на правильность ввода, помогите с удалением скобок макс вложенности, понятно что нужно считать заполнение стека и запоминать указатели, но не очень понятна реализация

```
ввод:(5+д)+[ () [] ]+([])
вывод: (5+д)+ [ ]+([])
```

полное задание:

Для каждой строки, представляющей собой запись некоторой математической формулы, проверить ее корректность с точки зрения соответствия друг другу открывающих и закрывающих круглых и квадратных скобок, а также, в случае корректности ввода, сформировать новую строку, из которой должна быть максимальной исключена подстрока, ограниченная круглыми скобками максимальной вложенности.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Item{
    char symb;
    struct Item *next;
}Item;

typedef struct List {
    Item *head;
    Item *tail;
} List;

typedef struct Stack {
    Item *head;
} Stack;

Stack *stack_new() {
    return (Stack *) calloc(1, sizeof(Stack));
}
List *list_new() {
    return (List *)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
}

int stack_push(Stack *stack, char symb) {
    Item *new = (Item *) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (!new) {
        return -1;
    }
    new->symb = symb;
    new->next = stack->head;
    stack->head = new;
    return 0;
}


void stack_print(const List *stack) {
    Item *ptr = stack->head;
    while (ptr) {
        printf("%c ", ptr->symb);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("*\n");
}

int list_push_back(List *list, char symb) {
    Item *ptr = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (!ptr){
        return -1;
    }
    ptr->symb = symb;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (!list->head) {
        list->head = ptr;
        list->tail = ptr;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = ptr;
        list->tail = ptr;
    }
    return 18;
}

void stack_delete_one(Stack *stack) {
    Item *ptr = stack->head;
    if(stack->head->next){
     stack->head= stack->head->next;
        free(ptr);}
        else if ((stack->head->next)== NULL){
            stack->head = NULL;
            free(ptr);
        }
}

void queue_delete(List *queue) {
    Item *ptr = queue->head, *ptr_prev;
    while (ptr) {
        ptr_prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free(ptr_prev);
    }
    free(queue);
}

void queue_delete1(Stack *queue) {
    Item *ptr = queue->head, *ptr_prev;
    while (ptr) {
        ptr_prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free(ptr_prev);
    }
    free(queue);
}


void move(Item *p1){
  while( p1->symb && ( ((p1->symb) != ']') && ((p1->symb) != ')')&&  ((p1->symb) != '(') &&  ((p1->symb) != '[') )){
                p1 = p1->next;
                 }
}

int prov(List *l)
{
  Stack *s = stack_new();
  Item *p1 = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
  p1 = l->head;
move(p1);

 if( ((p1->symb) == ']') ||  ((p1->symb) == ')') ){
                    printf("rrrr");
                    return 88;
                 }
while(p1)
{           if ( p1 && ( ((p1->symb) != ']') && ((p1->symb) != ')')&&  ((p1->symb) != '(') &&  ((p1->symb) != '[') )){
                p1 = p1->next;
                 }
               if( ((p1->symb) == '[') ||  ((p1->symb) == '(') )
                 {
                    stack_push(s, p1->symb);stack_print(s);
                    p1 = p1->next;
                 }

                 else if( (p1->symb) == ')')
                    {
                        printf("stack^1");
                            if(s->head && (s->head->symb) == '(')
                            {
                                   stack_delete_one(s);
                                   p1 = p1->next;

                          }else {
                                    printf("wronng1"); return 281;}
                 }
             else if( (p1->symb) == ']')
                {
                    if(s->head && (s->head->symb) == '[')
                    {
                       stack_delete_one(s);
                       p1= p1 -> next;
                   }
                   else {
                        printf("wronngg2"); return 282;}
                }
}
if((s->head) != NULL )
{
    printf("\nERROOOORR\n");
    return 24;
}

queue_delete(l);
queue_delete1(s);
free(p1);
return 55;
    }

int main()
{     int count_sk=0;
      char curr_cymb;
      List *l = list_new();
      while ((curr_cymb = getchar()) != '0' )
      {
           // if(  (curr_cymb==')') || (curr_cymb=='(')  || (curr_cymb==']') || ((curr_cymb=='[') ) )
            {list_push_back(l, curr_cymb);}
       /*if(  (curr_cymb=='(')  || ((curr_cymb=='[') ) ){
                 stack_push(s, curr_cymb);}*/
      }

      stack_print(l);
      prov(l);
      /*int m = prov(l);
      if(m==55){
        delete_long(l);

      }*/

      return 27;
}
```

Comment: Что-то ввод-вывод не очень соответствуют заданию... да и само задание - маловменяемое.

Comment: да, там ошибка в примере ввода вывода, ведь в задании только про макс вложенность круглых скобок, то есть 
ввод: () ( [] [] [] ) []
вывод: () (  ) []